# how to avoid calling `$parent` scope in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
app.directive('hidefileId',['$document','documentService',function($document,documentService){
    return{
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'AE',
        link : function($scope,element,attrs){
            element.on('click',function(e){
                angular.element('#fileId').removeClass("errorhilight");
                angular.element('#docerrormsg').html('');
            })

        }
    }

}]);
```

I have many directives in my js controller, when I use the following directive I am getting the parent scope in

$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.// here I am getting the scope of my controller.

even I use scope: false, it is creating new scope.

I want to use the my controller scope only

Comment: use [bindToController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: you can use require - https://toddmotto.com/directive-to-directive-communication-with-require/

Comment: may I know how can I use this require

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, click handlers are added with the `ng-click` directive, classes are added and removed with the `ng-class` directive, and error messages are shown with `ng-show` / `ng-hide` directives. Make the model the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) and build the DOM from the model.

Comment: Why do you want to access your controller scope? Why don't you isolate your directive's scope and pass the data you need of your controller to the directive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the require directive option. This will give you access to a parent controller(s). The directive with throw an exception if the controller(s) can not be found.  You will have access to anything you put on that controller. This is a great method to use if you need a parent child relationship where a child directive needs access to the parent. It also allows for more modular code.

e.g.
I have written a table directive with an exposed API to add formatting to cells. This is very useful as you can write many additional table directives that can be used interchangeably throughout an application. As an example I will show you a child HoverTitle directive that uses the parent table directive to add a hover tooltip in a given cell.

```
function HoverTitle(CellProcessService){
'ngInject';
return{
    require: '^cTable', // require c-table
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, cTable){

        cTable.addCellRenderProcess(renderCell, CellProcessService.priorities["HOVER-TITLE"]);
        function renderCell(curr, column, row){
            if(angular.isFunction(cTable.hoverClass)){
                var hoverTitle = cTable.hoverClass(row, curr, column);
                if(hoverTitle){ 
                    var placement = cTable.placement || 'right';
                    var tag = column.link ? "span" : 'a'
                    return '<' + tag + ' tooltip-placement="'+placement+'" uib-tooltip="' + hoverTitle + '">' + curr +'</ ' + tag + '>';
                }
            }
            return curr;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is how it could be used:

```
            <c-table
            table-sort
            hover-title
            data="$ctrl.data"
            columns="$ctrl.columns">
        </c-table>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: See also [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication).